# What is the purpose of generics before return type

Tags: java, generics, methods, generic-programming

For example, in the following code

```
public <U extends Number> void inspect(U u){
// Some method
}
```

what is the purpose of (what is this line doing or how is it read)
   
that comes just before the return type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the syntax that makes your *method* (as opposed to your *class*) generic.

Methods of regular and generic classes can be made generic on their own type parameters. In this case, your `inspect` method is generic on `U`, which must be a type extending from `Number`.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, but would this be acceptable then void inspect(<U extends Number>  u) ?

Comment: @johnwoolstock No. The syntax is as given in question.

Comment: @johnwoolstock No, unfortunately, that't the Java syntax (with the type coming before the return type).

Comment: Ah okay, that was exactly where my confusion was, makes sense now, Thanks!

Comment: @johnwoolstock In general you only need to do this if `U` appears at least *twice* in the signature. It wouldn't be a good idea to write `void inspect(<U extends Number> u, <U extends Number> u2)` because the point is that `U` is the same every time it appears, so it makes sense to appear at the front. Appearing before the return type makes Java slightly easier to parse because `U` could appear in the return type e.g. `<U extends Number> List<U> method(U u);`.