# Can someone explain this generic method

Tags: java, generics, methods, return-type

```
public static <K, V> boolean compare(Pair<K, V> p1, Pair<K, V> p2) {
        return p1.getKey().equals(p2.getKey()) &&
               p1.getValue().equals(p2.getValue());
    }
```

Through my research on generics, I have yet to stumble upon an answer that explains what the function of the generic before the return type serves, as in

```
<K, V>
```

that comes right before `boolean`.

Comment: Didn't you [just ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33468076/what-is-the-purpose-of-generics-before-return-type)?

Answer (score 0):

Generics enforce type-safety while allowing the types used to be anything the invoker specifies.

In this case, a compare method takes two Pair instances. The Pair class itself holds 2 instances. But of what data-types? This is what is specified by K and V.

So, to invoke this method on Pair objects that hold a string and an int, I would do the following

```
Pair p1 = new Pair<string, int>("hi", 1);
Pair p2 = new Pair<string, int>("bye", 2);
instance.compare(p1, p2);
```

If the two Pair instances had members of different types, then you would receive a compile-time error by the `compare` method, saying that the types do not match.